# this not refer to the correct instance

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have these two classes

```js
class Foo {
    name = 'Foo';

    foo() {
        const bar = new Bar(this.onSomething);
        bar.bar();
    }

    onSomething() {
        console.log(this);        //<= this where thing goes weird
    }
}

class Bar {
    name = 'Bar';
    constructor(onSomethingCallback) {
        this.onSomethingCallback = onSomethingCallback;
    }

    bar() {
        this.onSomethingCallback();
    }
}

const a = new Foo();
a.foo();
```

when the method `onSomething` called , `this` refer to the instance of `Bar` class instead of `Foo` class.

I expect `this` to refer to instance of `Foo` since the method `onSomething` is in `Foo`

Comment: you can give context to a method call by using method.call(context,parameters)

Comment: well, if you don't bind the this context, it will loose it as you have it now :)

Answer (score 1):

This is expected. If you bind `this.onSomething`, then its `this` will be set, otherwise, its `this` will be determined based on where its called from.

This is also the reason why `const $ = document.getElementById;` isn't usable, but `const $ = document.getElementById.bind(document);` is (because `getElementById` probably references `this` within).

```js
class Foo {
    name = 'Foo';

    foo() {
        const bar = new Bar(this.onSomething.bind(this));
        bar.bar();
    }

    onSomething() {
        console.log(this);        //<= this where thing goes weird
    }
}

class Bar {
    name = 'Bar';
    constructor(onSomethingCallback) {
        this.onSomethingCallback = onSomethingCallback;
    }

    bar() {
        this.onSomethingCallback();
    }
}

const a = new Foo();
a.foo();
```

See mdn for more info on [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#Function_context) and [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, that's how JS functions work. Calling a function as `foo.bar()` you're passing to it `foo` as the `this` context (0-th argument, if you will). A function called as `this/* Bar */.onSomethingCallback()` doesn't remember that it used to be a property of a different object.

And there are arrow functions, which just take the lexical `this`.

```js
class Foo {
    name = 'Foo';

    foo = () => {
        const bar = new Bar(this.onSomething);
        bar.bar();
    }

    onSomething = () => {
        console.log(this);        //<= this where thing goes weird
    }
}

class Bar {
    name = 'Bar';
    constructor(onSomethingCallback) {
        this.onSomethingCallback = onSomethingCallback;
    }

    bar = () => {
        this.onSomethingCallback();
    }
}

const a = new Foo();
a.foo();
```

Comment: There's no reason to make `foo` and `bar` class fields with arrow functions, you should keep them as methods. Only `onSomething` needs to become one.

Answer (score 0):

You are loosing context of `Foo` instanse because in this line `this.onSomethingCallback = onSomethingCallback;` you just put that function "out of context" and call it from `Bar` instance.

There are several preferred solutions:

1. bind `onSomething` in `Foo` constructor

```
class Foo {
  constructor () {
    this.onSomething = this.onSomething.bind(this);
  }
  ...
}
```

2. write `onSomething` function with arrow style

```
class Foo {
  onSomething = () => {...}
  ...
}
```

3. bind `onSomething` function just before passing it to `Bar` instance

```
class Foo {
  foo() {
    const bar = new Bar(this.onSomething.bind(this));
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```